# Adding whitespace to a TextView in Eclipse To Make Each Column a Fixed Length

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, whitespace

I am using a text file that stores 3 columns of data, each having varying length.

This is the following code I have tried so far.  I want each column to be left justified.  For some reason it works if I use an asterisk and not if I try to manually insert a whitespace.

(line is reading in 3 words from my text file)

Attempt #2:

```
while((line = buf.readLine())!= null){

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

    int length = 12;

    a = st.nextToken();
    while (a.length() <= length)
    {
        a = a + "*";
    }
    b = st.nextToken();

    while (b.length() <= length)
    {
       b = b + "*";
    }
    c = st.nextToken();

    text.append(a + b + c + '\n');
}
```

This was my original attempt but this did not work either:
text.append(String.format("%-15s\t %-10s\t %-5s\t \n",  a, b, c));

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is not to use just a single TextView for your three columns. You want to use a different TextView for each column and the control the formatting of each TextView individually. What type of layout are you using? If you switch to a [table layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html), it should be easy to left justify what ever you want. If your file will have a variable length, use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) which has three different text views in each row and then left justify each textview.

Comment: I am using RelativeLayout.. I am kinda new to this.. and I created a grocery store app and this is the last thing that needs to be done.  Would table layout work if I am using a single textview to display 3 columns of data  stored in a textfile?

Comment: thank you so much I honestly never thought of using multiple TextViews smh